# Delete a character in a .txt file using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, file

I am creating a program in VBA that takes tabular data on a spreadsheet in Excel and then prints each row as strings to a .txt file (that will be saved as a .jet file).  It begins with a header which is just a hard-coded string literal and then prints each Excel row after that, interweaving string literals between the cells of that row.  At the very end, it adds a footer which is just end braces.  The part I am stuck at is that i cannot figure out how to just delete the last comma in the .txt file because the commas are only used to separate between entries in the data.  I have prepared a similar example to the output text so far which includes that last comma that I want to delete:
`{"myid":345,"content":[ {"question": "A triangle is a shape with three straight sides?","answer": true}, {"question": "The moon is a planet","answer": false},`

EDIT:
Here is an example of some code.  I know half of it isn't real VBA code, or any code, but I am trying to give a sense of what I mean:

```
Open Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & filename For Edit As #1 ‘yes, I know there is no such “Edit”  
    Edit #1 SendKeys (bkspce) ‘yes, I know this is wrong.  im just saying something like sending a command to backspace, which wouldn’t work with SendKeys because it takes strings as arguments  
Close #1  
End Sub
```

Comment: you could use right and len functions something like right(variable holding the text, len(variable) -1) that would get rid of the last character. Is that the idea?

Comment: yes, the problem is, I am recreating a program that i already wrote because on the previous one, the strings became longer than would be stored in the variable, so I decided to put each entry on the .txt file one at a time. If I used right and len functions, as far as I know, that means I would have to capture the entire string of text on the file.  That puts me back on my string size limitation.

Comment: I see 2 options.  Either modify your creation logic to not add the comma for the last row, or process the file after the fact to remove the last comma.

Comment: @BrianMStafford I know.  The question assumes the latter.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the maximum number of chars a string variable can hold is up to [2GB or 2 Billion chars](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/strings-characters/string-data-type.htm). Are you hitting that limit?

Comment: I seriously doubt you are creating a text string longer than 2GB. Please confirm that's what you mean!

Comment: Alwys helps to post your code.  There are several approaches you could use, all of which would be easier to illustrate by us editing your code than by explaining in sentences.

Comment: My string is not longer than 2GB.  In my previous version of this program, the program would crash at the codeline to print the string to the .txt.  I then put a command prior to that line to make the value at an arbitrary cell to be the string value.  It was able to populate most of the string to that cell, but not the entire string.  Part of the reason I want to do this program is that I want to learn how to do file editing with Excel.  For example, random access in a file, sendkeys(which i heard is buggy, and only works with strings, not commands like backspace), etc.

Comment: In your post you describe the problems you're having with (I imagined) your code. Are you saying you have no code at all?  It might be a good time to try writing some: then we could help you with actual specific problems.

Comment: @TimWilliams I dont know how to do the code.  I have added some code to the original post.  I know it is wrong and half of it isn’t actually VBA code, but its just an example of my thinking

Comment: Forget *removing* the comma for now - the best approach is *not to add it in the first place*, so we really need to see the code which builds the file content.

Comment: @BrandonRedmond If you would like you can email your workbook and show me in there what your goal is and I will get it going for you. My email is: daniel.ferry@gmail.com

Comment: @ExcelHero Thank you very much for your offer.  I have decided to use a technique I know will work.  After I have finished the program as is, I will put comments in it for clarity and send it to you so you can advise me on how to do the solution for my understanding later.